# How to customize a function for a UI report when function is producing duplicates/triplicates of certain args [r]

Tags: r

I've created this function below that produces data that will go in a report in a UI.
However its not necessarily doing what I would like it to in the name and age arguments. It prints out the name and age in connection to how many orders there are. So if i.e. Customer ID 59 made 2 orders - her name will be printed out "Jane" "Jane" - I would like it to not do that.
If anyone has any idea on how to change this, i'd appreciate your input.

```
CustomerReport <- function(ID, Start_Date, End_Date) {
  
  CustomerOrders <- OrdersData[OrdersData$Customer_ID == ID & OrdersData$Date >= Start_Date & OrdersData$Date <= End_Date,]
  ProductOrders <- ItemsInOrders[ItemsInOrders$Order_ID %in% CustomerOrders$Order_ID,]
  CustomerInfo <- CustomersData[CustomersData$Customer_ID == ID,]
  
  Name <- paste(CustomerInfo$First_Name, CustomerInfo$Last_Name)
  Age <- CustomerInfo$Customer_Age
  NumberofOrders <- nrow(CustomerOrders)
  MeanTotals <- mean(ProductOrders$Quantities)
  MedianTotals <- median(ProductOrders$Quantities)
  PercentageType <- table(CustomerOrders$Type)/NumberofOrders
  PercentageBreakdown <- table(ProductOrders$Products)/nrow(ItemsInOrders)
  
  Result <- list(Name = Name, Age = Age, NumberofOrders = NumberofOrders, MeanTotals = MeanTotals,
                 MedianTotals = MedianTotals, PercentageType = PercentageType, PercentageBreakdown = PercentageBreakdown
                 )
  
  return(Result)
}
```

```
#Test the Customer Report Funcion

CustomerReport(1251, "2019-01-01", "2019-01-25")
```

the dput for the data frames

```
 dput(droplevels(CustomersData[1:5, ]))
structure(list(First_Name = c("Ariel", "Kinshasa", "May", "Gabrielle", 
"Jennifer"), Last_Name = c("Dirrim", "Purifoy", "Sue", "Finley", 
"Towns"), Customer_ID = c(1251L, 290L, 1714L, 381L, 109L), Customer_DOB = structure(c(11181, 
3956, 10632, 9742, 11145), class = "Date"), Customer_Age = c(20, 
39, 21, 24, 20)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

dput(droplevels(OrdersData[1:5, ]))
structure(list(Order_ID = c(69L, 3025L, 3549L, 27L, 4561L), Customer_ID = c(1251L, 
290L, 1714L, 381L, 109L), Date = structure(c(17899, 17921, 17925, 
17923, 17917), class = "Date"), Type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Delivery", "Pick Up"), class = "factor"), 
    Coupon = c("OFF10", NA, "LARGE10", "LARGE10", "LARGE10"), 
    Delivery_Fee = c("0", "12", "0", "0", "0"), Sub_Total_Before_Discount = c(27.98, 
    40.9, 74.94, 91.85, 80.82), Discount = c(2.8, 0, 7.49, 9.19, 
    8.08), Sub_Total_After_Discount = c(25.18, 40.9, 67.45, 82.66, 
    72.74), GST = c(2.52, 4.09, 6.74, 8.27, 7.27), Total = c(27.7, 
    44.99, 74.19, 90.93, 80.01)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

dput(droplevels(ItemsInOrders[1:5, ]))
structure(list(Order_ID = c(69L, 3025L, 3025L, 3549L, 3549L), 
    Products = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("BBQ Chicken Pizza", 
    "Meatlovers Pizza", "Seafood Pizza", "Supreme Pizza", "Vegetarian Pizza"
    ), class = "factor"), Prices = c(13.99, 13.95, 14.95, 13.99, 
    10.99), Quantities = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Everything else is perfect. Just the Names and the age are coming out in duplicates or triplicates.
Also, while we are here - is it possible to return the Percentage breakdowns as actual % values rather than 0.1 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `unique`. However, the behaviour you are describing isn't reproducible with the data you provided.

Try to replace the two lines getting the name and age information in your `CustomerReport` function:

```
  Name <- paste(unique(CustomerInfo$First_Name), unique(CustomerInfo$Last_Name))
  Age <- unique(CustomerInfo$Customer_Age)
```

Comment: @ismirsehrgal Thank you, that worked. Would you happen to know how to change the Percentage breakdowns to return as 50% rather than 0.5?

Comment: should be something like `PercentageBreakdown <- paste0(table(ProductOrders$Products)/nrow(ItemsInOrders) * 100, "%")`

Comment: Yeah, that worked. although it only worked for the PercentageType not the Break down. It's okay though, im still able to get the same results. Thank you.